# ajax call does not display the new data

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have an ajax call that should look in the folder for new images after each loop, And display new images in the next cycle, but its not working correctly

here is my html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1000"/>
    <title>Slideshow</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #slideshow {
        position: relative;
      }
      #slideshow,
      #slideshow img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #eee;
      }
      #slide {
        width: 370px;
        height: 220px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      #myslides {
        width: 370px;
        height: 220px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      #myslides img {
        padding: 10px;
        border:  1px solid rgb(100,100,100);
        background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
        width: 350px;
        height: 200px;
        top:  0;
        left: 0
      }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadSlides() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "loadajax.php"
        }).done(function(response) {
          var temp_images = eval("(" + response + ")");
          for(ti in temp_images)
          {
            //alert(temp_images[ti]);
            $('#slideshow').append('<img src="images/' + temp_images[ti] + '" alt="">');
          }
          startSlideshow();
        });
      }

      function startSlideshow()
      {
        $('#slideshow').cycle({
          fx: 'fade',
          speed: 700,
          timeout: 800
        });
      }

      $(document).ready(function(){
        loadSlides();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slideshow" />
  </body>
</html>
```

and  my php code:

```
<?php

function returnimages($dirname="./images") {
  $pattern="([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";
  $files = array();
  if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
      if(preg_match($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
        $files[] = $file;
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
  //sort($files);
  natcasesort($files);

  return($files);
}

$images = returnimages();
echo json_encode($images);

?>
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call `jQuery.ajax()` and don't attach at `.fail()` callback to the returned [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) in the same way as you have attached a `.done()` callback, you get nothing if the request fails for any reason.

So what we can establish here is that your request is failing.  Or not being run in the first place.

To track down problems like these, use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the developer tools built into chrome.  Both of them have a "network" tab that shows you all of the requests the browser makes, with full details.  You can use these to determine if the request is actually being initiated, as well as the result.

Comment: i installed firebug and and from the log it appears that everything is working okay but it seems it reloads eveything from cache, is there a way to clear cache before the next cycle? http://i43.tinypic.com/2cn8klf.jpg

Comment: Holding down shift while you click the reload button usually does the trick.